# Is there any graph api like below screen, can put color gradient?

Tags: css, angularjs, graph

I would like to know is there any graph api that generates bar graph exactly shown below, same color combination and same type

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find way to do it using chart.js or any js apis. So created one here https://github.com/munawer-t/bar-chart-using-pure-css3-and-angularjs#bar-chart-using-pure-css3-and-angularjs